# Edit / add item to Resources.resx

Tags: c#

i try to add Items dynamically to the Resources.resx. 
At the moment im tying using a RessourceWriter, but this is not working ( it produces *.resources files and dont write into the .resxfile).

```
 ResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("Resources.resx");
        writer.AddResource(string.Concat("AppImage",indes.ToString()), newImg);
        writer.Close();
```

Can somebody tell me what im doing wrong, or is it even impossible to add items dynamically to Ressources.resx ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resx files are designed to be filled with resources at development/design time, not at run time, remember that there is a resource designer class that contains auto generated code by the IDE.

You can fill you resx file in a project pre-build event.

Comment: By the way there are specialized tools for localization that update  resx files, check http://www.schaudin.com/web/Home.aspx for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to update your resx files at run time.

```
string ResxFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Properties/Resources.resx");
string wordResxName = resxname;
string word = resxvalue;
string ResxAddStrings = "  <data name=\"" + wordResxName + "\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\r\n    <value>" + word + "</value>\r\n  </data>\r\n";
ResxAddStrings += "</root>";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Properties/Resources.resx", ResxFile);
```